# Formula 1 Free practice without a super licence

Tags: rules, formula-1

Formula One drivers must have an [FIA Super Licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIA_Super_Licence), but what about (young) drivers who take part only in free practice sessions? Are they allowed to drive without the license?

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.autoweek.com/article/20130715/f1/130719903): "A major hurdle will be obtaining a mandatory FIA F1 super license, which is necessary even for Sirotkin to conduct practice sessions for Sauber."

Comment: @aufkag yeah, thanks for the link, it seems that the drivers need the licence indeed, I found some information and added it as answer

Comment: Reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_One): "Drivers may also be issued a Super License by the World Motor Sport Council if they fail to meet the criteria." This suggests you don't need the _FIA_ Super Licence per se.

Comment: @aufkag it's the same. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIA_World_Motor_Sport_Council) too: The World Motor Sport Council (WMSC) is the most powerful body of the Fédération Internationale de l'Automobile (FIA)

Comment: Ah, yes, I misinterpreted the quote. :) It refers to "By exception, if supported by the FIA Safety Commission, the
FIA World Motor Sport Council may approve the issue of the
Super Licence to persons judged by the Council to have met
the intent of the qualification process." (From [this pdf](http://argent.fia.com/web/fia-public.nsf/C30FA5AA9E36713DC125786B004EDCFC/$FILE/11.04.07_Annexe%20L_%202011.pdf).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, drivers without the super licence are not allowed to take part in the free practice sessions. From [formula1.com](http://www.formula1.com/inside_f1/rules_and_regulations/sporting_regulations/8694/fia.html):

> [...] each team will be permitted to run
>   additional drivers during P1 and P2 provided :
>
> - the stewards are informed which cars and drivers each team intends to use in each session before the end of initial scrutineering,
>     changes after this time may only be made with the consent of the
>     stewards ;
> - no more than two drivers are used in any one session ;
> - they carry the race number of the nominated driver they replace ;
> - they use the engine and tyres which are allocated to the nominated driver ;
> - **they are in possession of a Super Licence.**

Comment: ...and if you're interested, [this news article](http://www.crash.net/f1/news/198067/1/whitmarsh_super_licences_a_apossensitive_areaapos.html) has some quotes from McLaren's Team Principle, Martin Whitmarsh, who explains a little about how the Super Licence is actually granted.

Answer (score 2):

The young drivers who drive in the free practice sessions of a Grand Prix are required to have a Super License from FIA, as said in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_One_racing).

However, young drivers who take part in the Young Drivers Test are not required to posses a Superlicense, as the YDT is not part of a FIA F1 Grand Prix.